# wordpress advanced custom fields and polylang integration

Tags: php, wordpress, translation, advanced-custom-fields, polylang

I used ACF plugin to build my page, I wanted to create the page that client could change what he wants in it. But I need to translate this page into 5 languages. I installed polylang, can't buy a pro version. I want to that my custom fields could be translatable, for now i can create a page in different languages, but they share custom fields, so if i set english version for it it would be seen in all language versions... I've search through the internet and can't find a working solution. Maybe someone here could help me. I would be very happy to read your solutions. Thanks.

Comment: Could you use WPML instead? https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/multilingual-custom-fields/

Comment: WPML is also paid... need something free or I will have to rebuild whole site and not use acf? :(

Comment: check the first reply to this thread.  https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/acf-and-polylang-languages-not-shown/   maybe it can help you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to go into your Polylang settings and under Syncronization, **uncheck** the "Custom fields" box. This will allow you to have different languages.

[Source](https://polylang.pro/doc/synchronize-metadatas-between-translations/)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add that if you are dealing with "Theme Options", we did https://github.com/BeAPI/acf-options-for-polylang plugin to support this core-unsupported feature.
It’s a selfworking plugin, nothing to do after installation.
If you have some issues, inquirements, improvements or requests please refer to the github. I will be glad to help you.
So please check it out!

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue, in my case i had to connect the language versions https://prnt.sc/1u99vor. Add translation for the original page and you are set to go. Btw i am using Polylang free.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29964758)

Comment: @Toni Ok, got it !